# basic question about php multiple FOREACH loops

Tags: php

I have few FOREACH loops in php;

```
$c1 = 1;
$c2 = 1;
$c3 = 1;

foreach ($someArray as $a){
    echo $a;
    if (sizeof($someArray != $c1){
        echo " / ";
    }
    $c1++;
}

foreach ($otherArray as $b){
    echo $b;
    if (sizeof($otherArray != $c2){
        echo ", ";
    }
    $c2++;
}

// etc.
```

This seems somehow stupid, of course =) Is there any way to avoid declaring variables with same values and to use them in many FOREACH loops?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Are you referring to the $c counter variables?

Comment: Some indication as to what the purpose of the code is would be helpful.

Comment: Also, watch out for syntax and logic errors. `if (sizeof($someArray) != $c1) {`

Comment: Ah yes, sorry for the typo... =(
The purpose of code is just some general displaying of a multidimensional array from mysql query...

Comment: You should accept answers to your original questions, and make a new question when you have one.

Comment: OK, sorry... I will do it in the future... This was my first posting here so I was little bit confused with all the comments/answers etc =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears you are trying to do what the following code does much better:

```
$line = implode(' / ', $someArray);
echo $line;

$line = implode(', ', $otherArray);
echo $line;
```